# .Net Entity Many to Many SaveChanges

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have been playing with Entity Core classes such as DbContext and had the following error trying to save an object:

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.

I basically have my erd with a many to many such as

```
comment   comment_category   category
id        comment_id         id
text      category_id        name
```

the comment_category table is a combo primary key to map comments to categories

retrieving data is fine but when I try to save it complains about the relationship

the models I am most interested in look like

```
public class Comment
{
   [Key]
   public int Comment_Id {get;set;}
   public string Text {get;set;}
   public virtual List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
} 
public class Comment_Category
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Comment_Id {get;set;}
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int Factor_Id {get;set;}
}
```

And its used such as

```
#Comments have Categories with Category Id filled and Comment Id null
List<Comment> comments = getComments();
using(dbContext db = new dbContext())
{
  foreach( Comment c in comments)
    db.Comments.add(c);
  db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am not entirely sure why it can find it easily enough but has a hard time saving. The only difference I can think of is that the comments I am saving are new so they only have Comment Categories with no Comment id just category ids. I assumed that it would save the comment and assign the comment_id to the comment_category table so I am not sure how to accomplish this

I realize that perhaps my approach is wrong in that I am using the mapping table as opposed to the actual entity for categories so if anyone knows  a better way please share.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this without a lot of ceremony is to also have a collection of Comments on Category and let Entity Framework infer the M:M relationship. It will automatically create a CategoryComments table with primary and foreign keys.

So for the model we simply have:

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int Comment_Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Category_Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Usage would be something like:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}

using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    var blue = new Category { Name = "Blue" };
    var red = new Category { Name = "Red" };
    db.Categories.Add(blue);
    db.Categories.Add(red);

    db.Comments.Add(new Comment
    {
        Text = "Hi",
        Categories = new List<Category> { blue }
    });

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This approach seems like the intended and in the case of a new Schema makes complete sense. In my case I have an existing Schema that I do not have control over so I have tables mapped and defined a particular way.

Comment: @user1876229 Out of curiosity, have you tried using the [Entity Framework Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) and reverse engineered to see what is generated? I find it can be a useful tool to see examples of how EF thinks things should be. Never going to be perfect of course.